# Why won't my docker-cmd execute with sh?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

**CMD ["./run-nginx.sh"]**  script doesn't execute and throws **panic: standard_init_linux.go:175: exec user process caused "exec format error" [recovered]**. Why so? Could you help :( my machine is  win10 and docker version :  Docker version 1.12.3,

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx
ADD run-nginx.sh /usr/app/src/
ADD setup-index-page.sh /usr/app/src/
WORKDIR /usr/app/src/
RUN chmod +x run-nginx.sh
RUN chmod +x setup-index-page.sh
CMD ["./run-nginx.sh"]
```

**run-nginx.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
./setup-index-page.sh
exec nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

**setup-index-page.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
container_id=${hostname}
color=${container_id:0:6} echo "<body>Serving you from container id: ${hostname}</body>" > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
```

**Response**

```
panic: standard_init_linux.go:175: exec user process caused "exec format error" [recovered]
panic: standard_init_linux.go:175: exec user process caused "exec format error"
2017-01-01T06:48:38.776636000Z 
goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
panic(0x88f8a0, 0xc820136a10)
```

Comment: is it possible you're trying to run this under windows docker, when you should be using linux docker?

Comment: Sorry, I dont use docker container on linux because of using microsoft tecnology.

Comment: well nginx appears to be a linux container.  So what do you mean, you're using microsoft technology?

Comment: I mean that , I am using docker on OS and  want demo what has a single nginx  running at docker container .

Comment: Do you think your docker container runtime environment is windows or linux?

Comment: my docker version
Client: 
OS/Arch:      windows/amd64


Server:
Version:      1.12.3
API version:  1.24
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Is it clear for you?

Comment: It seems like that should be correct, but since it's throwing an exec format error, I'm sticking with my original theory in the absence of a better one.  Can you get _any_ linux container to run?

Comment: Yeah , I used  a load balancer (haproxy container) and 4  node (ngnix containers)  and it was running successfully in the morning . But I get errors like abow when I want to run some  additional linux coding as "sh" in DockerFile .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the fact that you are mapping the volume from Windows to Linux, it is very likely that your *.sh files have Windows style (CRLF) line endings. If you convert them to Unix/Linux style (LF), it should be fine to go.

I am not sure about the right tools on Windows to check and fix the line endings but Notepad++ should be able to do it.

Comment: yessssss :) I build and save  *.sh files with Notepad++. It is up. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tested your codes on my system with a linux docker backend ( osx actually, so there's no question about what docker backend OS is running), and it worked fine ( though I didn't get a container ID).  I think your issue is that you've configured docker in your windows environment to run windows containers, not linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a script as the entry point for your container, it may have somehow had DOS carriage returns added to the ends of the lines. As a result, your shebang will appear to the Linux shell as `#!/bin/bash^M`. The `^M` may be invisible in vim. To see it, run:

```
vim -U NONE -u NONE filename
```

To remove it, from inside vim run:

```
:%s/\r//g
```

**NOTE:** Make sure to run vim with above options first.

The most common cause of this is editing files in Windows. However, it will also happen if you created the file by running `cat` with `docker exec` and the `-t` flag. The `-t` flag causes execution in TTY mode, which prints DOS carriage returns at the ends of the lines. Instead run without any flags:

```
docker exec mycontainer cat /path/to/file > file_on_host
```